# How to write multiprocessing code correctly in Python 2

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement very simple multiprocessing code in python 2.7, but it looks like the code run serially and not parallel.
The following code prints *****1***** while I expect it to print *****2***** immediately after *****1*****.

```py
import os
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep


def main():
    func1_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1())
    func2_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2())

    func1_proc.start()
    func2_proc.start()

    pass

def func1():
    print "*****1*****"
    sleep(100)

def func2():
    print "*****2*****"
    sleep(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The two spawned processes run independently, why do you expect any order of output?

Comment: The order is not the issue, that code prints just one line while I expect 2 lines.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `func1` and `func2` before passing their returning values to `Process`, so `func1` is going to sleep 100 seconds before returning `None`, for which `Process` will raise an error.

You should pass function objects to `Process` instead so that it will run them in separate processes:

```
func1_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1)
func2_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2)
```

Comment: Just note, that on most systems, this will not give an output, as print in a subprocess is not piped to stdout of the main process per default.